# Pandasで小数点以下の桁を保持したままdataframeに読み込むには？

Tags: python, pandas

現在、次のような内容のcsvファイルを読み込み、dataframeを作成したいと考えています。

ファイル名：gis_points_data.csv
この中身

```
index_gis,fX,fY
0,139.75192,35.70077
1,139.77791,35.6997
2,139.7467,35.70089
3,139.75908,35.69649
4,139.7747,35.69283
5,139.74051,35.68449
```

ファイルを読み込むと、fXとｆYの桁がまるめられてしまい、
fXは、140に、fYは35.7になってしまいます。
これでは、区別がつかなくなってしまうので、小数点以下の桁は、そのまま
読み込み、後での計算に使用したいのですが、
どのようにすれば、小数点以下の桁をそのまま保持した形で、読み込むことができるのでしょうか？

現在のところ、下記のようなコマンドを試していますが、
いずれも同じ結果になります。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#そのまま読み込む場合
df0=pd.read_csv("gis_points_data.csv")

# 型を倍精度浮動小数点型に指定
df1=pd.read_csv("gis_points_data.csv", 
                     dtype={'fX':'float64','fY':'float64'})

# 文字列に読み込み、のちに変換
df2=pd.read_csv("gis_points_data.csv", 
                     dtype={'fX':'object','fY':'object'})
df2['fX']=df2['fX'].astype(float)
df2['fY']=df2['fY'].astype(float)
```

Comment: オプション無して read_csv 使うと3桁に丸められることはないので、display.float_format 等で有効数字を3桁で表示するような設定をしていませんか。df0['fX'] - 140 とするとわかります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。df0['fX']としたところ、小数点以下の桁も表示されていました。spyderを使っているのですが、そちらでは、140とだけ出ていましたので、勘違いしていたようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_csv`をオプション無しで使った場合、数字が3桁に丸められることはないので、単に表示がそのようになっているだけと思われます。丸められた数字を引くと本当に丸まられているのか、それとも表示だけなのかがわかります。

```
print(df0['fX'] - 140)
```

なお、表示の有効桁数は、`Pandas`では `display.float_format`で、`iPython`の方だと`%precision`で設定することができます。